# Apex Logging for Managed Package

Tags: apex, package, logging, managed-package

I log my apex code exceptions using getStackTraceString(). I understand that this is not visible to a customer log normally. But I already logged in to our LMA and logged in to the subscribers org and still the error message is still hidden.

I have searched for answers but all the forums say is logged through your LMA, which I did. But still only seeing our namespace in the logs.

Comment: Try to disable logs (delete log settings) and recreate from your LMA. Sometimes some glitch happens, and that step works